# GIF Images on Visualforce does not display properly in IE vesrions

Tags: visualforce, images, internet-explorer

I'm displaying a GIF image on a Visualforce page but it doesn't display properly on Internet Explorer versions (Displays larger and out of given style scales). But the GIF is displayed according to given scales in other browsers (Chrome, Mozilla). Following are the VF lines used:-

```
<apex:image style="width:20%;height:20%;" value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MWiz,'images/Loader.GIF')}"/>
```

I also tried to use the GIF directly from a web page for the value, but still displays the same. Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: i have noticed this as well and switched to jpg or png